# Php DB Microsoft Access запрос

Tags: php, pdo, ms-access

Помогите исправить ребята. Пробовал прописать в конфиг Apache 
      AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Список товаров</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
  $dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/php/elara/Borey.mdb";
    if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
        die("База данных не найдена");
    }
    else {
        echo "Успех!";
    }

    try {
        $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Подключение не удалось: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'Товары'";
    if ( ! $result = $db->query($sql)) {
        die(var_export($db->errorinfo(), TRUE));
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Выдает ошибку:
   Успех!array ( 0 => 'HY000', 1 => 0, 2 => '[Microsoft][������� ODBC Microsoft Access] �������������� ������ � �������. �������� ����������� �������. (SQLPrepare[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_driver.c:206)', 3 => '', )

Comment: А в правильной кодировке сообщение об ошибке никак?

Comment: В правильной кодировке ошибку не показывает. Только то что я написал.

Comment: а чем мотивирован выбор СУБД для связки с PHP? оно конечно встречается, но весьма редко.

Comment: `charset` попробуйте указать в настройках подключения PDO

Comment: На заводе используется, все связано с access.

Comment: Попробовал charset, не помогло.